# Navigation of .NET MAUI Application

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have created several singletons and added them onto my .NET MAUI application. I have also registered their routes. I am best explaining these using analogies. If I have a stack of papers and I would like to go back one page I manage to flip back to that one page, but if I want to go back one more page I can't an error pops up and application crashes saying unhandled error.

I know there are two methods to Navigate my stack of paper using Shell.Current.GoToAsync. Is there any tutorial or could you provide an example on how to navigate more than 3 pages.

I have tried using:

```
[RelayCommand]
        /*
         * async Task Back_Main()
         * {
         *      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
         * }
         */
        async Task Back_Main()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(MainPage)}");
        }
```

However, I am just confused because it works when I move one page but when I am two pages ahead it doesn't seem to work anymore. I also need it work for navigating back to other pages as well let say if I am on Page 2 and move to Page 4 I need to able to go back to page 2. Any tips, advice, or YouTube videos are appreciated. I am not necessarily looking for a coded answer I would like to learn this myself.

I tried that and it did not work it I was wondering if there was something that I was missing in my setup.

[Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation) I used for reference. This link was good but I was confused how it says it mimics a stack I was hoping it could mimic a LinkedList where I could reference the pages in any order because the individual pages know the page in front and page behind.
Code Snippets:
2nd Page View Model

```
[RelayCommand]
    async Task Back_Main()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
    /*
     * async Task Back_Main()
     * {
     *      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
     * }
     */

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Back_Main1()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../MainPage");
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Back_General()
    {
        try
        {
            await Back_Main();
            Back_Main().Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            await Back_Main1();
            Back_Main1().Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Routes App Shell CS:

```
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(2ndPage), typeof(2ndPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(3rdPage), typeof(3rdPage));
    }
}
```

In the application it is supposed to have 9 pages that a user clicks the bottom buttons to move forward to next page. However, if they entered something wrong they should be able to freely go back to one of the pages.

The task of Navigation has to be done via buttons and not tabs due to HCI constraints.

Comment: What did user do to "move forward" from page to page? They click buttons? If so, then there was some gotoasync call? Give an example of a sequence of forward moves (gotoasyncs?) that were called based on user actions, that you now are trying to undo.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I added the bottom portion about the 9 pages and going back and forth.

Comment: Those are **Tabs**. Clicking them just switches between them. User "goes back" by clicking whatever tab they want to be on. They are not placed on a navigation stack; that isn't how tabs work. Its like picking up one piece of paper, then putting it back where you got it, and picking up a different one. No memory of where you came from.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve In theory if I had data that I needed to be saved from each tab to the final tab would that data be accessible in the final tab?

Comment: There is no magic: pages and other views are simply c# classes. Accumulate the data somewhere that all the tabs can access. Three ways to get the data to final tab: * a static variable somewhere; * Messenger Publish/Subscribe; * MVVM + DI where all tabs use the same ViewModel, which is registered as a Singleton, and injected into each tab class'es constructor using DI. Search for more info on each topic, as desired.

Comment: Do you still meet this issue? If so, could you please share more detailed information about what the expected behavior is and how does that differ from the actual behavior?